# How to split df column into df row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this

```
id shortTextContent shortTextCode longPlainTextContent longTextCode semiTextContent semiTextCode
1  shortContent1         shortCode1         long1                longCode1    semiContent1    semiCode1
2  shortContent2         shortCode2         long2                longCode2    semiContent2    semiCode2
```

How should I split it into the following content? (where the column names become row content, like below)

```
id content               content            code
1  shortTextContent      shortContent1      shortCode1
1  longPlainTextContent  long1              longCode1
1  semiTextContent       semiContent1       semiCode1
...
```

Comment: `pd.wide_to_long`

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=[1,2,3,4],other=['a','b','c','d']))
df_melted = pd.melt(df)
```